# how apply another rule to wordpress htaccess with more than three parameters

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I have an URL on WP made website like this:

```
http://www.example.org/location-results/?range=25&cat=attractions&subcat=-&latd=53.04304&lng=-2.992493999999965
```

that want to be like this:

```
http://www.example.org/location-results/attractions/-/near/wrexham/25/53.04304/-2.992493999999965
```

searched about htaccess to to this, and tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php 
RewriteRule location-results/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/? index.php/?page_id=5371&range=$5&cat=$1&subcat=$2&latd=$6&lng=$7 

</IfModule>
```

and got error 404.
this one does not work either:

```
RewriteRule location-results/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/? location-results/?range=$5&cat=$1&subcat=$2&latd=$6&lng=$7 [L]
```

what is my mistake? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I found [this useful post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule) and got help from [a friend on twitter](https://twitter.com/SMostafaMoosavi)
so finally solved in this way:

1-Removed .htaccess file

2-Regenerated it from permalink settings on WP admin

3-Changed **cat** to **thecat** because its reserved key

added these codes to **function.php**

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
           flush_rewrite_rules(false);
    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
        add_rewrite_rule(
                // The regex to match the incoming URL
                '^location-results/([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)/near/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9\-\.]+)/([0-9\-\.]+)$',
                // The resulting internal URL: `index.php` because we still use WordPress
                // `pagename` because we use this WordPress page
                // `thecat,subcat,range,latd,lng` because we assign the first captured regex part to this variable
                'index.php?pagename=location-results&thecat=$matches[1]&subcat=$matches[2]&range=$matches[4]&latd=$matches[5]&lng=$matches[6]',
                // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
                // Otherwise, the "catch-all" rules at the bottom (for pages and attachments) will "win"
                'top');
    } 
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

and

```
function wpa5413_query_vars($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'thecat';
    $query_vars[] = 'subcat';
    $query_vars[] = 'range';
    $query_vars[] = 'latd';
    $query_vars[] = 'lng';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpa5413_query_vars', 10, 1);
```

4-Changed **$_GET** to **get_query_var** and **SOLVED!**

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks almost right, but you haven't escaped `/`. Also, not sure what's the purpose of `/?` at the end, you could omit it I guess. The result is:

```
RewriteRule location-results\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*) location-results/?range=$5&cat=$1&subcat=$2&latd=$6&lng=$7
```

Comment: this is test URL: http://www.agespace.org/location-results/attractions/-/near/wrexham/25/53.04304/-2.992493999999965

that must map to http://www.agespace.org/location-results/?range=25&cat=attractions&subcat=-&latd=53.04304&lng=-2.992493999999965

Comment: @Amino I seem to have copied a wrong example of yours, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

replace `*` with `+` so that you have a clear error message when empty values are requested add `[L]` parameter to the end.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^location-results/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page_id=5371&range=$5&cat=$1&subcat=$2&latd=$6&lng=$7  [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

1- remove anything in `htaccess`

2- Set `htaccees` file permission to 777 (for a short time);

3- Go to 
`http://www.website.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`

and add your custom url Structure and save change.

if you get **404 Error**

1- Make sure [RewiteModule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enable on your Apache

2- if you still give 404 error then:

go to Apache Configuration:

path usually on `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

open it on notepad and find`AllowOverride` and change **No** to **All**